# Synonyms, Outer Joins, and String Functions

Tags: mysql, string, oracle, outer-join, synonym

How do I return all postal codes for a country from the orders table to return the postal code in format `xxx-xxx` in sql?.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to accomplish this?

Comment: what's you table structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These SQL will useful to you.

```
  MYSQL:-   SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('524401', 1, 3),'-',SUBSTRING('524401', 4, 6));
```

---

```
oracle: SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(524401), 1, 3),'-',SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(524401), 4, 6)) FROM DUAL;
```

Thank you.

Comment: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
00909. 00000 -  "invalid number of arguments"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Comment: can you provide sample data also?

Comment: I updated my answer can you check it once. mysql query you are trying in oracle database it will not work. I updated oracle sql you can check it.